# How to pass data in two way data binding in class base component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My problem that is in a child component, I have a state that updated via post method and I must show this state in my parent component both these component are the class base component

Comment: Put some code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReactJS is a library with **One directional data binding**. So that is not possible to pass data like *Angular* or *VueJS*. you should pass a handler function to the child-component and then after the *Axios* answer update the local and also the parent component.

And there is a little hint here, there is no different for your situation between *class components* and *functional components*. pay attention to the sample code:

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: undefined,
  };

  handleGetData = data => {
    this.setState({
      data,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent onGetData={this.handleGetData} />
    );
  }
}
```

And now inside the *ChildComponent* you can access to the handler function:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMound() {
    const { onGetData } = this.props;

    Axios
      .get('someSampleUrl')
      .then( (data) => {
        onGetData(data); // running this update your parent state
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React's practice is one-directional. For best practice, you must 'Raise' the states into the parent component.

But if you were looking specifically to pass data up, you need to pass a callback down as a prop. use that callback function to pass the data up:

Parent:

```
<Parent>
   <Child callback={console.log} />
</Parent>
```

Child:

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const { callback } = props;
    const postData = (...) => {
        ...
        callback(result);
    }
    ...
}
```